# R: apply() type function for two 2-d arrays

Tags: r, data-structures

I'm trying to find an apply() type function that can run a function that operates on two arrays instead of one.

Sort of like:

```
apply(X1 = doy_stack, X2 = snow_stack, MARGIN = 2, FUN = r_part(a, b))
```

The data is a stack of band arrays from Landsat tiles that are stacked together using rbind.  Each row contains the data from a single tile, and in the end, I need to apply a function on each column (pixel) of data in this stack.  One such stack contains whether each pixel has snow on it or not, and the other stack contains the day of year for that row.  I want to run a classifier (rpart) on each pixel and have it identify the snow free day of year for each pixel.

What I'm doing now is pretty silly: `mapply(paste, doy, snow_free)` concatenates the day of year and the snow status together for each pixel as a string, `apply(strstack, 2, FUN)` runs the classifer on each pixel, and inside the apply function, I'm exploding each string using `strsplit`.  As you might imagine, this is pretty inefficient, especially on 1 million pixels x 300 tiles.

Thanks!

Comment: So for a given column `i`, it would be something like `snow_free(doy_stack[,i], snow_stack[,i])`?

Comment: @Aaron Yep, exactly right.  I can't figure out the `apply` that as two `X` values to pass to the `FUN`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I wouldn't try to get too fancy.  A for loop might be all you need.

```
out <- numeric(n)
for(i in 1:n) {
  out[i] <- snow_free(doy_stack[,i], snow_stack[,i])
}
```

Or, if you don't want to do the bookkeeping yourself,

```
sapply(1:n, function(i) snow_free(doy_stack[,i], snow_stack[,i]))
```

Comment: Great advice! Fanciness sometimes takes so much developer's focus & time which isn't effective anymore! Unless you really need CPU speed optimizations. Otherwise simple for loop does the job better & is quick to write the code.

Answer (score 3):

I've just encountered the same problem and, if I clearly understood the question, I may have solved it using `mapply`.

We'll use two 10x10 matrices populated with uniform random values.

```
set.seed(1)
X <- matrix(runif(100), 10, 10)
set.seed(2)
Y <- matrix(runif(100), 10, 10)
```

Next, determine how operations between the matrices will be performed. If it is row-wise, you need to transpose X and Y then cast to `data.frame`. This is because a `data.frame` is a `list` with columns as list elements. `mapply()` assumes that you are passing a `list`. In this example I'll perform correlation row-wise.

```
res.row <- mapply(function(x, y){cor(x, y)}, as.data.frame(t(X)), as.data.frame(t(Y)))
res.row[1]
     V1 
0.36788
```

should be the same as

```
cor(X[1,], Y[1,])
[1] 0.36788
```

For column-wise operations exclude the `t()`:

```
res.col <- mapply(function(x, y){cor(x, y)}, as.data.frame(X), as.data.frame(Y))
```

This obviously assumes that `X` and `Y` have dimensions consistent with the operation of interest (i.e. they don't have to be exactly the same dimensions). For instance, one could require a statistical test row-wise but having differing numbers of columns in each matrix.

Answer (score 2):

Wouldn't it be more natural to implement this as a raster stack? With the `raster` package you can use entire rasters in functions (eg `ras3 <- ras1^2 + ras2`), as well as extract a single cell value from XY coordinates, or many cell values using a block or polygon mask.

Comment: It certainly sounds like a more natural data structure.  What I'd need is way to apply the classification function (rpart), pixel by pixel through the raster stack, carrying the raster day-of-year along with it.  Maybe a raster stack and a day-of-year array?

Comment: @cswingle: Check out `stackApply` and `calc` from this package if you are interested.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers.  Those look like nice functions, and I'll certainly keep them in mind for other processing tasks.  The issue for me in this case is that I need something like `stackApply` where the function applied gets two vectors (in my case, the snow state vector and the day of year vector) and returns a single value.

Answer (score -1):

`apply` can work on higher dimensions (i.e. `list` elements). Not sure how your data is set up, but something like this might be what you are looking for:

```
apply(list(doy_stack, snow_stack), c(1,2), function(x) r_part(x[1], x[2]))
```

Comment: When I try something similar, R reports an error inside the function when it tries to access `b` because it's not being passed.  As far as the structure, I think `doy_stack` and `snow_stack` are both matrices:  each row starts as an array that is then attached to the bottom of the stack using `rbind`.  `rbind(array, array)` appears to yield a matrix.

Comment: @cswingle yes, I did not check it, just blindly put in the function you mentioned. Check the update.

Comment: Thanks.  I see what you're going for, but I can't get the dimensions to work out, probably because I've got a different data structure than what you're imagining (and I haven't provided an example. . .).  Aaron's solution above does seems to work.